flask celery worker not recieving tasks
I'm working on a task where I need to schedule my application to execute at regular intervals using Celery Beat schedule.
The main issue I'm facing is that Celery is not triggering my application at the specified interval.
Could anyone help me with this?
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import xmltodict
import json
import logging
import os
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery import Celery
from .celery import make_celery
from datetime import timedelta
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Event(db.Model):
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    provider_id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    started_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    end_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    sell_mode = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=db.func.current_timestamp())

    def as_dict(self):
        """
        Converts the Event object to a dictionary representation.
        Returns:
            dict: Dictionary representation of the Event object.
        """
        return {
            "provider_id": self.provider_id,
            "name": self.name,
            "datetime": self.started_at.isoformat(),
            "sell_mode": self.sell_mode
        }

def remove_at_sign(obj):
    
    """
    Recursively removes '@' sign from keys
    """
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {key.lstrip('@'): remove_at_sign(val) for key, val in obj.items()}
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [remove_at_sign(elem) for elem in obj]
    else:
        return obj

def fetch_events():
    """
    Fetches events data from an external API and processes it.
    Returns:
        list: List of Event objects fetched from the API.
    """
    
    PROVIDER_URL = 'some-url'
    response = requests.get(PROVIDER_URL)
    events = []
    if response.status_code == 200:
        json_resp = xmltodict.parse(response.text)
        final_json = remove_at_sign(json_resp)

        with open('events.json', 'a') as f1:
            json.dump(final_json, f1, indent=4)

        final_data = final_json['eventList']['output']['base_event']
        for ind, data in enumerate(final_data):
            if 'sell_mode' in data and final_data[ind]['sell_mode'] == 'online':
                sell_mode = final_data[ind]['sell_mode']
                title = data['title'] if 'title' in data else str()
                start_date = datetime.fromisoformat(data['event']['event_start_date'])
                end_date = datetime.fromisoformat(data['event']['event_end_date'])
                event_id = data['event']['event_id']
                events.append(Event(provider_id=event_id, name=title, end_at=end_date, sell_mode=sell_mode, created_at=datetime.now(), started_at=start_date))
                print([sell_mode, title, start_date, end_date, event_id])
    return events

def store_events(events, app):
    """
    Stores events in the database.
    Args:
        events (list): List of Event objects to be stored.
        app (Flask): Flask application instance.
    """
    
    
    with app.app_context():
        try:
            db.session.add_all(events)
            db.session.commit()
            logging.info(f"Stored {len(events)} new events in the database.")
        except Exception as e:
            db.session.rollback()
            logging.error(f"Failed to store events: {str(e)}")
            raise

def fetch_and_store(app):
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        events = fetch_events()
        store_events(events, app)

def create_app():
    # import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///events.db'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    app.config.update(
        CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0',
        CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
    )
    db.init_app(app)

    celery = make_celery(app)
    celery_worker = 'worker1@hostname'
   

    # Configure logging
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    log_file = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'app.log')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(file_handler)

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()


        @celery.task(name='app.scheduled_fetch_and_store')
        def scheduled_fetch_and_store():
            fetch_and_store(app)
            
            

        celery.conf.beat_schedule = {
            'fetch-events-every-10-seconds': {
                'task': 'app.scheduled_fetch_and_store',
                'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10), 
            },
        }
        

        @app.route('/events', methods=['GET'])
        
        def get_events():
            """
            Retrieves events filtered by start and end dates.
            Returns:
                jsonify: JSON response containing events data.
            """
            
            starts_at = request.args.get('starts_at')
            ends_at = request.args.get('ends_at')
            logger.info(f"Fetching events between {starts_at} and {ends_at}")

            if not starts_at or not ends_at:
                logger.error("Both 'starts_at' and 'ends_at' parameters are required")
                return jsonify({"error": "Both 'starts_at' and 'ends_at' parameters are required"}), 400

            try:
                starts_at = datetime.fromisoformat(starts_at)
                ends_at = datetime.fromisoformat(ends_at)
            except ValueError:
                logger.error("'starts_at' and 'ends_at' must be in ISO format")
                return jsonify({"error": "'starts_at' and 'ends_at' must be in ISO format"}), 400

            events = Event.query.filter(Event.started_at >= starts_at, Event.end_at <= ends_at).all()
            result = [
                {
                    "id": event.provider_id,
                    "name": event.name,
                    "start_time": event.started_at.isoformat(),
                    "end_time": event.end_at.isoformat(),
                    "sell_mode": event.sell_mode
                } for event in events
            ]

            with open('sample.json', 'w') as json_file:
                json.dump(result, json_file, indent=4)

            return jsonify(result)

        @app.route('/routes', methods=['GET'])
        def list_routes():
            import urllib.parse
            output = []
            for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
                options = {}
                for arg in rule.arguments:
                    options[arg] = f"[{arg}]"
                methods = ','.join(rule.methods)
                url = urllib.parse.unquote(f"{rule}")
                line = f"{rule.endpoint:50s} {methods:20s} {url}"
                output.append(line)
            return "<pre>" + "\n".join(sorted(output)) + "</pre>"

    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=True)

`I have set up a schedule using Celery to execute my application every 10 seconds, but it's not working.
I have used these commands in terminal

Python3 run.py
celery -A celery worker --loglevel=info
celery -A celery worker --beat --loglevel=info

It throws me this type of warnings :
\[2024-07-10 16:55:53,498: INFO/MainProcess\] Connected to amqp://guest:\*\*@127.0.0.1:5672//
\[2024-07-10 16:55:53,499: WARNING/MainProcess\] /home/bhupesh/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:507: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
warnings.warn(

\[2024-07-10 16:55:53,534: INFO/MainProcess\] mingle: searching for neighbors
\[2024-07-10 16:55:53,543: WARNING/MainProcess\] No hostname was supplied. Reverting to default 'localhost'
\[2024-07-10 16:55:54,571: INFO/MainProcess\] mingle: all alone
\[2024-07-10 16:55:54,624: INFO/MainProcess\] celery@vijay-latitude-7480 ready.




celery -A celery worker --beat --loglevel=info


Shouldn't you run Celery beat like this: celery -A celery beat -l info?
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler

I have tried this, but it's not worth it
